# Building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker, torch

I'm working on a program that needs to be linked to libtorch_lite, and [Essentia](https://essentia.upf.edu), on iOS, and have had Essentia working on iOS for a while, but when trying to add the torch dependency, which requires the `-all_load` linker flag to work at runtime, and I got this error:

> ld: in
> /Users/sylmorrison/JUCE_old/UserModules/kalide_extractors_juce/libs/iOS/arm64/libessentia.a(nnls.c.1.o),
> building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS, file
> '/Users/sylmorrison/JUCE_old/UserModules/kalide_extractors_juce/libs/iOS/arm64/libessentia.a'

A `lipo -info` on libessentia.a returns arm64 and arm7, and if I leave out the -all_load flag everything works fine, but torch errors at runtime (undefined reference to aten::unsqueeze)

Because torch has a load of extra dependencies, and because I thought I just needed the `-all_load` flag *somewhere*, I thought I'd try compiling it into a static library, and then linking to that library, but doing that results in the same error. I also tried modifying Essentia's build script to add an `all_load` flag (out of desperation mostly), which didn't get me anywhere. Any suggestions would be amazing, am at a loss about what's going on, it's like Xcode, when the `all_load` flag is enabled, convinces itself it's a macOS static library. If it makes a difference, I'm using an M1 Mac mini on Monterey

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed it by figuring out which files essentia wanted to compile when cross compiling for iOS, copying them and the headers to a new folder, and then making an Xcode project to build an iOS static library, I guess due to the cross compiling somehow some of the object files were actually for macOS?